# Qt 6.3 unable to deploy to device (windows 10)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, qml

I installed Qt 6.3 ,Android Studio 7 (Chipmunk 2021.2.1),java jdk-11.0.15+10  NDK Version: 22.1.7171670).The Android build Platform Sdk 32.
The jdk does not have jre.
A screenshot is attached.
I am using gradle 5.6.4

When I deploy to Android it fails with the following error log (compile output).

"
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\o\Documents\build-TrackGate-Android_Qt_6_3_0_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug\android-build\build.gradle' line: 17
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android-build'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
> Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.0.2. Current version is 5.6.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\o\Documents\build-TrackGate-Android_Qt_6_3_0_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug\android-build\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-7.0.2-all.zip

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 17s
Building the android package failed!
18:55:35: The process "C:\Qt\6.3.0\mingw_64\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project TrackGate (kit: Android Qt 6.3.0 Clang armeabi-v7a)
When executing step "Build Android APK"
18:55:36: Elapsed time: 06:45. "

when i change to gradle7.0.2 i get

"adb.exe: device 'DVKS100I21060300956' not found
...
Installing to device failed!
19:11:44: The process "C:\Qt\6.3.0\mingw_64\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 16.
19:11:44: Installing the app failed with an unknown error.
...
19:11:44: The command "C:\Users\o\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s DVKS100I21060300956 pull /system/bin/app_process C:/Users/o/Documents/build-TrackGate-Android_Qt_6_3_0_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/app_process" terminated with exit code 1.
19:11:44: Package deploy: Failed to pull "/system/bin/app_process" to "C:/Users/o/Documents/build-TrackGate-Android_Qt_6_3_0_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/app_process
...
19:11:44: The command "C:\Users\o\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s DVKS100I21060300956 pull /system/bin/app_process32 C:/Users/o/Documents/build-TrackGate-Android_Qt_6_3_0_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/app_process" terminated with exit code 1.
19:11:44: Package deploy: Failed to pull "/system/bin/app_process32" to "C:/Users/o/Documents/build-TrackGate-Android_Qt_6_3_0_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/app_process".
...
19:11:44: The command "C:\Users\o\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s DVKS100I21060300956 pull /system/bin/linker C:/Users/o/Documents/build-TrackGate-Android_Qt_6_3_0_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/linker" terminated with exit code 1.
19:11:44: Package deploy: Failed to pull "/system/bin/linker" to "C:/Users/o/Documents/build-TrackGate-Android_Qt_6_3_0_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/linker".
...
19:11:44: The command "C:\Users\o\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s DVKS100I21060300956 pull /system/lib/libc.so C:/Users/o/Documents/build-TrackGate-Android_Qt_6_3_0_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/libc.so" terminated with exit code 1.
...
19:11:44: Package deploy: Failed to pull "/system/lib/libc.so" to "C:/Users/o/Documents/build-TrackGate-Android_Qt_6_3_0_Clang_armeabi_v7a-Debug/libc.so".
Error while building/deploying project TrackGate (kit: Android Qt 6.3.0 Clang armeabi-v7a)
When executing step "Deploy to Android device"

"
Assist in setting-up the environment because an android device is connected via usb.

Comment: _Minimum supported Gradle version is 7.0.2. Current version is 5.6.4_. I would start investigating the problem exactly from this point. Then ... _adb.exe: device 'DVKS100I21060300956' not found_ ... this also looks suspicious.

Comment: I also get this from issues ":-1: warning: Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times."

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to deploy to device by uninstalling everything related to Qt, Java and and Android Studio. I reinstalled Qt 6.3.1 and used Qt to install Java and Android Studio .I made sure that the Arm64 v8 system image for API 30 is available in Android Studio.
This video link "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrQ_j6VOnzo" helps with Qt 6 installation .
This video link "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WafdjRhyDRc" helps with Android Studio installation